# Assign a conditional column with the text "type" and succeeding number based on every two rows

Tags: r, conditional-statements

For example i have a data frame with two columns

```
 Name|Job
 Dave  1  
 Matt  1 
 Jes   3  
 Chris 1  
 Jen   4  
 Cal   2
```

I want the script to make this outcome

```
Name|Job|type
 Dave  1  type 1
 Matt  1  type 1
 Jes   3  type 2
 Chris 1  type 2
 Jen   4  type 3
 Cal   2  type 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rep(…, each = 2L)` creates two elements of each vector.

`seq_len(nrow(df) %/% 2L)` creates a vector of numbers 1, 2, …, n, where n is the number of your classes.

Putting it together:

```
df$type = paste('type', rep(seq_len(nrow(df) %/% 2L), each = 2L))
```

Another, potentially more typical, way of generating classes is via the `cut` function (although it’s much more code in this case):

```
n_types = 3L
types = cut(seq_len(nrow(df)), n_types, labels = seq_len(n_types))

df$type = paste('type', types)
```

Comment: perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
#Code
df$type <- paste0('type',sort(rep(c(1:(nrow(df)/2)),2)))
```

Output:

```
df
   Name Job  type
1  Dave   1 type1
2  Matt   1 type1
3   Jes   3 type2
4 Chris   1 type2
5   Jen   4 type3
6   Cal   2 type3
```